# Connecting Neo4J with SpringBoot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-neo4j

I need help in connecting neo4j database to spring boot. I have been googling thi the whole day but not able to figure out. I can create a spring boot Application, create a REST controller that calls the Service and then the Spring data JPA repositories for SQl, but not able to do it for graph database, Can anyone please help me configuring the Graph database to spring boot.
I am new to Neo4j and has been assigned a task.

thank you.
I added whatever any tutorial told me:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.3.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-neo4j</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.data/spring-data-neo4j-rest -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-neo4j-rest</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>neo4j-configuration</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0-alpha08</version>
    </dependency>


</dependencies>
<properties>
    <start-class>com.sumit.demo.AppBootConfig</start-class>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>
<build>
    <finalName>people</finalName>
</build>
```

my main is:

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = { Neo4jDataAutoConfiguration.class })
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = { DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class })
public class AppBootConfig extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(AppBootConfig.class, args);
     }
}
```

I tried to configure but got this:

```
017-04-25 01:10:03.316  WARN 5772 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to process import candidates for configuration class [com.sumit.demo.AppBootConfig]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [org/springframework/data/neo4j/config/Neo4jConfiguration.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist
```

2017-04-25 01:10:03.323 ERROR 5772 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Destroy method on bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.internalCachingMetadataReaderFactory' threw an exception

java.lang.IllegalStateException: ApplicationEventMulticaster not initialized - call 'refresh' before multicasting events via the context: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@2f9f7dcf: startup date [Tue Apr 25 01:10:02 IST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getApplicationEventMulticaster(AbstractApplicationContext.java:404) [spring-context-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationListenerDetector.postProcessBeforeDestruction(ApplicationListenerDetector.java:97) ~[spring-context-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DisposableBeanAdapter.destroy(DisposableBeanAdapter.java:253) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroyBean(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:578) [spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroySingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:554) [spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.destroySingleton(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:959) [spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroySingletons(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:523) [spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.destroySingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:966) [spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.destroyBeans(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1033) [spring-context-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:555) [spring-context-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) [spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:761) [spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:371) [spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) [spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1186) [spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1175) [spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
    at com.sumit.demo.AppBootConfig.main(AppBootConfig.java:15) [classes/:na]

2017-04-25 01:10:03.334 ERROR 5772 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to process import candidates for configuration class [com.sumit.demo.AppBootConfig]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [org/springframework/data/neo4j/config/Neo4jConfiguration.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:541) ~[spring-context-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processDeferredImportSelectors(ConfigurationClassParser.java:475) ~[spring-context-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:184) ~[spring-context-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:308) ~[spring-context-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:228) ~[spring-context-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:270) ~[spring-context-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:93) ~[spring-context-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:686) ~[spring-context-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:524) ~[spring-context-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:761) [spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:371) [spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) [spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1186) [spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1175) [spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
    at com.sumit.demo.AppBootConfig.main(AppBootConfig.java:15) [classes/:na]
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [org/springframework/data/neo4j/config/Neo4jConfiguration.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:172) ~[spring-core-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.(SimpleMetadataReader.java:50) ~[spring-core-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:98) ~[spring-core-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.type.classreading.ConcurrentReferenceCachingMetadataReaderFactory.createMetadataReader(ConcurrentReferenceCachingMetadataReaderFactory.java:89) ~[spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.type.classreading.ConcurrentReferenceCachingMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(ConcurrentReferenceCachingMetadataReaderFactory.java:76) ~[spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:93) ~[spring-core-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.asSourceClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:633) ~[spring-context-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser$SourceClass.getSuperClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:797) ~[spring-context-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:308) ~[spring-context-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:230) ~[spring-context-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processMemberClasses(ConfigurationClassParser.java:329) ~[spring-context-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:247) ~[spring-context-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:230) ~[spring-context-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:532) ~[spring-context-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    ... 15 common frames omitted

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, Your pom is quite messy. Only add the dependencies which are needed. you only need this

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-neo4j</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>  
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-neo4j-rest</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.6.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

your main class should have something like this

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableNeo4jRepositories("com.in.neo4j.repository.neo")
```

I am not sure why you are excluding some autoconfigurations

Comment: I was getting this error thats why i excluded them. `Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [org/springframework/data/neo4j/config/Neo4jConfiguration.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist at ` I guess that might work

Comment: still getting `class path resource [org/springframework/data/neo4j/config/Neo4jConfiguration.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist` error

Comment: check your springboot parent and spring-data-neo4j versions if they are compatible.

Answer (score 0):

The reference which you are giving doesn't contain **Application.properties** .

Hence Here is **Application.properties** file to connect to your Neo4j.

```
spring.data.neo4j.uri=bolt://localhost
spring.data.neo4j.username=neo4j
spring.data.neo4j.password=Your_Password
```

Start your Neo4j Database as a console application which will run on localhost:7474 port most probably.

command to start:

```
neo4j console
```

Also check the dependency. As the latest version work with only

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-neo4j</artifactId>
</dependency>
```